# How to do input user calculation in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

i need to do a multiply calculation based on user input. so user have to input a value in Input A and Input B, then the Input C will automatically calculated those multiplication between input A and B. does anyone have any idea on how to do that in sapui5?

i tried to do a calculation using a formatter for value input C but it seems didnt work. after i enter the Input B, there's no value in Input C

```
<Label text= "Rate"/>
                <Input id ="Project Rate" value=""/>

                <Label text="Discount"/>
                <Input type="Number" id="inputB"/>

                <Label text="Total Rate"/>
                <Input id="inputC" enabled="false" 
                        value="{parts:[
                                        {path: '/ProjectRate'},
                                        {path: '/Discount'},
                                        {path: '/TotalRate'}],
                                        formatter: 'calcProjectRate'}"/>


calcProjectRate: function(ProjectRate, Discount, TotalRate) {
        if (ProjectRate && Discount) {
            TotalRate =  ProjectRate * Discount / 100;
            return TotalRate;
        }
        return "0";
```

Comment: Can you prepare jsfiddle for sample code? You need to use change event for triggering calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has error, you need to check your IDE code check result.

- id values cannot include space, for example "Project Rate"

Working example below (may be it is not best solution).

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
  "use strict";
  sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
    onInit: function() {

    }
  });
  sap.ui.xmlview({
    viewContent: jQuery("#myView").html()
  }).placeAt("content");
});

calcProjectRate = function() {
  ProjectRate = this.oView.byId("ProjectRate").getValue();
  Discount = this.oView.byId("inputB").getValue();
  TotalRate = 0;
  if (ProjectRate && Discount) {
    TotalRate = ProjectRate * Discount / 100;
  }
  this.oView.byId("inputC").setValue(TotalRate);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>SAPUI5</title>
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

<script id="myView" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="MyController" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout">

    <layout:MatrixLayout>
      <layout:rows>
        <layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
          <layout:MatrixLayoutCell backgroundDesign="Fill1" padding="None">
            <Input id="ProjectRate" value="" liveChange="calcProjectRate" />

            <Label text="Discount" />
            <Input type="Number" id="inputB" />

            <Label text="Total Rate" />
            <Input id="inputC" enabled="false" />

          </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
      </layout:rows>
    </layout:MatrixLayout>


  </mvc:View>
</script>

<body class="sapUiBody">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```